# How to get TF2 Bots to move?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have followed a thing for how to get bots to move. I chose a gamemode that bots support(PL) and it has a navmesh. The only thing is they stand still like they don't have  a navmesh. PLease help.

Comment: I figured it out. No answers needed xD I was using the bot command instead of tf_bot_add

Answer (score 2):

From OP:

You need to use the `tf_bot_add` command instead of `bot`.